# onchange copy field value from select to input with the same number

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy

I have a bunch of select boxes with numbered classes. I have the same amount of input fields with numbered classes. Whenever a select box is added by the user it numbers the class up and automatically creates a new input with the same number as well. So `selectbox1` has `input1` as companion.

Now I need to copy the selected value from the selectbox to the input. This I partially got working but at the moment it is copying to all the inputs.

Here is the code:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".selectArea").each(function(i) {
      $(this).addClass("selectBox" + (i+1));
    });
    var values = $("input[id^='jform_params__characters__characters'][id$='__character_name']").map( function(){return $(this).val(); }).get();
    var optionsPlaceholder = '###OPTIONS###';
    var optionPlaceholder = '###OPTION###';
    var select = '<select class="selectInput">' + optionsPlaceholder + '</select>';
    var option = '<option>' + optionPlaceholder + '</option>';
    var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var currentOption = option.replace(optionPlaceholder, values[i]);
        options += currentOption;
    }
    var selectBox = select.replace(optionsPlaceholder, options);
    var $select = $(selectBox);
    $(".selectBox").html($select);
    $(".selectInput").each(function(i) {
      $(this).addClass("selectInput" + (i+1));
    });
    $("input[id^='jform_params__storymaker__storymaker'][id$='__characterselection_save']").each(function(i) {
      $(this).addClass("selectInputSave selectInputSave" + (i+1));
    });
  });

  $(document).on('change', '.selectInput', function() {
    alert(this.value); // or $(this).val()
    $('.selectInputSave').val($(this).val());
    //$('.selectInputSave' + (i+1)).val($(this).val());
  });
})(jQuery);
```

The problem lies in the `$(document).on('change'` function. 
As you can see when I use

```
$('.selectInputSave').val($(this).val());
```

then it copies it to all the inputs fields which is normal so I though to do this.

```
$('.selectInputSave' + (i+1)).val($(this).val());
```

but it says that `i` is not defined. Which is true as it is not so I tried defining it by reusing a part of the code in the `doc.ready` function. Only when I did that the strangest behaviour happened. The first selectbox value would be copied to the last input???

## the question

How can I implement this `i+1`? So that `selectInput1` gets copied to `selectInputSave1` etc etc.

It needs to be dynamic as the user can create unlimited selectboxes.

Thank you very much for helping out!

Comment: copy and test this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xogzvsjf/5/

Comment: Note: `(i+1)` will give `01,11,21,31` to make it like `1,2,3,4,5,6` use `(+i+1)`

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer I tried your suggestion it puts in all the inputs a number 2? Thanks for the note. Good looking out. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with html?

Comment: No sorry that is not possible it is inside the Joomla CMS system which it heavily relies on. I wished it was possible.

Comment: Ok, what i made setting value of each option with ( i ) then `onchange` you will get selected option value as class index. so i think this should work. define what issues you face or what console errors says.

Comment: All the inputs became a 2 and the selectbox itself became empty. Because of this it gave me the idea to use the class of the selectbox itself. So inadvertently with your suggestion and fiddle you made me come up with another way which is working. I can't thank you enough for pointing me in the right direction. I am posting the solution in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with inspiration from Mamdouh Freelancer. His comments made me think about getting the class number from the selectbox and use that number to add to the class where you want to save it.

So I extracted the class > replaced the text part leaving me with a number.
Then I added this number to the input where I wanted to save it to and it works.

Select 1 saves to Input 1

Select 2 saves to Input 2

Select 3 saves to Input 3

Etc Etc.

Here is the code.

```
  $(document).on('change', '.selectInput', function() {
    var savevalue = (this.value);
    alert(this.value); // or $(this).val()
    var selectClassRaw = $(this).attr("class").replace('selectInput selectInput', '');
    alert(selectClassRaw);
    $('.selectInputSave' + selectClassRaw).val(savevalue);
  });
```